# Issue with existing phone gap code demonstrated by adobe

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, adobe

These days i am trying to run an existing code from Adobe's Technical Evangelist Andrew Trice. The concept is to connect a database.com DB to phone gap application. here is the tutorial with the source code :

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Building_PhoneGap_Mobile_Applications_Powered_by_Database.com

THE ISSUE :

AFTER SUCCESSFUL INSTALLATION OF THE Childbrowser there is a specific error in the code :

Uncaught type error: cannot read property "ChildBrowser" of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/salesforceWrapper.js:17

here is the full code : ( i put comment in the line with the error)

```
function SalesforceWrapper() {
    /* AUTHENTICATION PARAMETERS */
    this.loginUrl = 'https://login.salesforce.com/';
    this.clientId = '3MVG99qusVZJwhsmjZIlEaUsFRnadOib8Kv_MPwooFMEi.XpChrZ5cVEcKU_7NR1zfQjjmdHI7wMARXnLlgku';
    this.redirectUri = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success';

    /* CLASS VARIABLES */
    this.cb = undefined;     //ChildBrowser in PhoneGap
    this.client = undefined; //forceTk client instance

    this.init();
}

SalesforceWrapper.prototype.init = function() {
    this.client = new forcetk.Client(this.clientId, this.loginUrl);
 // line 17 with the error
    this.cb = window.plugins.childBrowser;
}

SalesforceWrapper.prototype.login = function (successCallback) {
    this.loginSuccess = successCallback;
    var self = this;
    self.cb.onLocationChange = function (loc) {             
        if (loc.search(self.redirectUri) >= 0) {
            self.cb.close();
            self.sessionCallback(unescape(loc));
        }
    };
    self.cb.showWebPage(self.getAuthorizeUrl(self.loginUrl, self.clientId, self.redirectUri));
}

SalesforceWrapper.prototype.getAuthorizeUrl = function (loginUrl, clientId, redirectUri) {
    return loginUrl + 'services/oauth2/authorize?display=touch' + '&response_type=token&client_id=' + escape(clientId) + '&redirect_uri=' + escape(redirectUri);
}

SalesforceWrapper.prototype.sessionCallback = function(loc) {    var oauthResponse = {};

    var fragment = loc.split("#")[1];

    if (fragment) {
        var nvps = fragment.split('&');
        for (var nvp in nvps) {
            var parts = nvps[nvp].split('=');
            oauthResponse[parts[0]] = unescape(parts[1]);
        }
    }

    if (typeof oauthResponse === 'undefined' || typeof oauthResponse['access_token'] === 'undefined') {
        console.log("error");
    } else {
        this.client.setSessionToken(oauthResponse.access_token, null, oauthResponse.instance_url);
        if ( this.loginSuccess ) {
            this.loginSuccess();
        }
    }
    this.loginSuccess = undefined;
}
```

ADOBE'S PHONE GAP IS A DANGEROUS TOOL , BUT IT IS STILL SO TOUGH TO MANIPULATE.

THANK YOU APRIORI FOR YOUR POSSIBLE PROPOSALS . AT THIS POINT I DON'T EXPECT TO GET THE ANSWER. I KNOW THAT THERE IS A BIG DISTANCE...

Answer (score 0):

well people the problem was caused because of the index.html in which the reference of the childbrowser.js was in different folder.

it was in :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/ChildBrowser.js"></script>
```

instead of :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ChildBrowser.js"></script>
```

SO PEOPLE BE CAREFULL!!!

NOW MY PROBLEM HAS TO DO WITH ANOTHER FUNCTION BUT I THINK THAT IT IS SOMETHING SIMILAR.

THANK YOU ALL!

PLEASE TRY TO ANSWER IF YOU KNOW SOMETHING.